# Windows Server 2019 - Unable to create File from Right Click

Tags: windows-server-2019, context-menu

Windows Server 2019.

I've created a new user account and added it to the Administrators Group.

I've disabled the built-in Administrator account for security.

When using the new Administrative user account it seems to be missing a lot of right click context menu actions such as Create Shortcut, Create File, etc. The only context action I can see is 'Create Folder'.

Additionally every time I try to do something Windows is asking for Administrative access even though I'm logged in with Administrative privileges.

Any idea how to restore these missing context menu actions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was unable to directly replicate the problem you describe. Was that menu working on the default account ?

Comment: Yeah on the default account everything worked as normal. I thought it might be related to RDP but I've logged physically on to the server, same issue. I have the full context menu available on the desktop, but not any other folder on the Server. In fact I have full context menu access anywhere in the C:\Users\*** directory but not the rest. Looks like its permissions issue but I would have thought making myself a member of Administrators would automatically resolve that. I might try and manually reapply permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behavior if UAC is enabled and the account only has permissions via a protected group like Administrators. If you assign permissions to the account or another group for which the account is a member, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's solved it. I thought by adding the account to the Administrators group then the account should automatically inherit the Administrators group permissions but obviously not the case. I've applied the permissions for the specific account and that has solved it. Thanks,